# onChange is not working in reactstrap custom input switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Code:

```
import { CustomInput } from 'reactstrap'
...
const changeMediaStatus = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
}
...
<CustomInput
   type="switch"
   className="ml-auto mr-1"
   onChange={(e) =>changeMediaStatus(e)}
/>
```

On the above code, the function that is assigned at "onChange" prop is not working. And also, CustomInput component with onChange prop is not working.

How can I assign a function to onChange event at reactstrap CustomInput compoenent?

Comment: onChange is working here - https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-kare-puf0q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but on your sandbox, CustomInput is seen as a normal checkbox.

Comment: set `id` for custom input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `id` for the CustomInput.

```
<CustomInput
      type="switch"
      id="id-1"
      className="ml-auto mr-1"
      onChange={(e) => changeMediaStatus(e)}
    />
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-1ttkao?file=Example.js